# What is the meaning and purpose of Active Directory Primary Group?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I recently heard of the Primary Group concept in Active Directory but it so far it's quite unclear that is its purpose and how this really works.

As part of the same question, how do I get the Primary Group using LDAP ? It seems that this is not listed as a `memberOf` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this code to get the primary group of a user in Active Directory:

```
private string GetPrimaryGroup(DirectoryEntry aEntry, DirectoryEntry aDomainEntry)
{
   int primaryGroupID = (int)aEntry.Properties["primaryGroupID"].Value;
   byte[] objectSid = (byte[])aEntry.Properties["objectSid"].Value;

   StringBuilder escapedGroupSid = new StringBuilder();

   // Copy over everything but the last four bytes(sub-authority)
   // Doing so gives us the RID of the domain
   for(uint i = 0; i < objectSid.Length - 4; i++)
   {
      escapedGroupSid.AppendFormat("\\{0:x2}", objectSid[i]);
   }

   // Add the primaryGroupID to the escape string to build the SID of the primaryGroup
   for(uint i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   {
      escapedGroupSid.AppendFormat("\\{0:x2}", (primaryGroupID & 0xFF));
      primaryGroupID >>= 8;
   }

   // Search the directory for a group with this SID
   DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();

   if(aDomainEntry != null)
   {
       searcher.SearchRoot = aDomainEntry;
   }

   searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=Group)(objectSID=" + escapedGroupSid.ToString() + "))";
   searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");

   return searcher.FindOne().Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString();
}
```

The primary group is a group that every new user is added to by default - usually `Domain Users`.